# How to add Custom Component Image to Wide Column

Tags: home-page-component

Custom component image are only available on narrow column (Text from help : An image that will be displayed in the sidebar (Example: your company logo) ).I have the image in the documents folder How to add Image to wide column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display an image in the wide area by creating an HTML component and then editing the source and creating an image tag.  Here are the steps to get it done.

**Image Prep**

1. Make sure that you have your image as externally availble.
2. Copy the URL to the image.  Do this by right clicking on the image and copying the image URL, or opening the image in a new link.  It should be something like: `https://c.na15.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015i0000001kbjE&oid=00Di0000000LLLL&lastMod=1387647307000.`

**Component Creation**

1. Instead of selecting to create an Image, select to create an HTML component.
2. You will be taken to a rich text editor.  Check the show HTML checkbox which will show the HTML source of your component (initially blank).
3. Type an img tag in the source.  For example: `<img src="https://c.na15.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015i0000001kbjE&oid=00Di0000000LLLL&lastMod=1387647307000" />`'. Note that you can also set width and height if you please.
4. Finish up and save.

You should now be able to add that  component in the wide column.

You can get creative once you have the image in the HTML component.  For instance, you could center it and add some text and end up with something like the following...

[image: Merry XMAS]